# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in my test

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I know this has been asked many times but I can't figure it out. :(

I have a big project and the structure is like:

```
Project - build
        - Config
        - src
        - tst
        - build.xml
        - webapp
        - eclipse-bin
```

There is a java file under tst/com/myspace/gateway/content/restlet/SanityTest.java
In the java file:

```
package com.myspace.gateway.content.restlet;
...
public class SanityTest extends ContentGatewayRestletResourceTestCase {
...
public static void main() {
}
}
```

After the whole project compiles, the class file of SanityTest is under build/private/classes/tests/com/myspace/gateway/content/restlet/SanityTest.class

I went into build/private/classes/tests and ran "java -cp . com.myspace.gateway.content.restlet.SanityTest" but got the NoClassDefFoundError.

Please help me!

PS:
Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myspace/gateway/content/ContentGatewayTestCase
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:         com.myspace.gateway.content.ContentGatewayTestCase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
Could not find the main class: com.myspace.gateway.content.restlet.SanityTest.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: wow I need to re-structure my code...

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError can happen even if you have the class correctly in classpath. Reason can be failing static code or any othrr exception while classloader tries to load the class

Comment: Can you give copy the full error including stack trace into your question? Use the "edit" button please, and properly format it.

Comment: Why do you roll back formatting changes? Do you think it looks better unformatted?

Comment: Be careful where you're running your command line <java> <-cp whatever path>  <package.MainClass>  If I were using maven to build my project and say it would put my classes into two separate folders, one called ./classes/ and another ./test-classes/ to run my Main file I would have to somehting of the form:  

D:\Data\myUser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DeleteMe\target>java -cp ./classes/;./test-classes/ launcher.Main

|
Lisbon   <--- Program output
public class Main {
Launcher
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new pt.MostBeautifulCity().getName());
    }
}

Comment: By the way - I would recommend that you discard the old-school way of building projects in an IDE where you select the "project" nature - jar - war whatever. Eclipse loves that you do that. Just don't! use maven and if the IDE hates maven, discard the IDE.

Comment: The project is built primarily using Ant I  think. Looks like com.myspace.gateway.content.ContentGatewayTestCase is missing. I'm looking into that...

Answer (score 0):

You ran

```
java -cp . com/myspace/gateway/content/restlet/SanityTest
```

You should have run:

```
java -cp . com.myspace.gateway.content.restlet.SanityTest
```

Read this Q&A for more details:

- [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

---

**UPDATE**

According to the stacktrace, the problem is that Java cannot find the `ContentGatewayTestCase` class.  Presumably, that is a class that your `SanityTest` class depends on.  However, the source code snippet shows that `SanityTest` extends `ContentGatewayRestletResourceTestCase`.  You need to figure out if the `ContentGatewayTestCase` dependency is correct:

- If it is, the corresponding ".class" file needs to be in the same directory as your "SanityTest.class" file.
- Either way, you probably have a problem with the way you are compiling your code.

Comment: I did run java -cp . com.myspace.gateway.content.resetlet.SanityTest. My mistake in the OP, I will update it.